# How to check Android Asset resource?

Tags: android, resources, assets

I want to check, whether a file exists or not in the /assets/ folder.
How could I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform your own checks. As I know, there is no method for this job.

Comment: Understandable that there might not be a method for this, but if you can't provide an alternative then this shouldn't have been an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I added a helper method to one of my application classes.  I'm assuming that;

1. the list of assets doesn't change while the app is running.
2. the `List<String>` isn't a memory hog (only 78 assets in my app).
3. checking exists() on the List is faster than trying to open a File and handle an exception (I haven't actually profiled this).

> ```
> AssetManager am;
> List<String> mapList;
>
> /**
>  * Checks if an asset exists.
>  *
>  * @param assetName
>  * @return boolean - true if there is an asset with that name.
>  */
> public boolean checkIfInAssets(String assetName) {
>     if (mapList == null) {
>         am = getAssets();
>         try {
>             mapList = Arrays.asList(am.list(""));
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>         }
>     }
>     return mapList.contains(assetName);
> }
> ```

Comment: `List.contains()` already returns boolean, no need for the ternary expression at the end of function.

Answer (score 8):

You could also just try to open the stream, if it fails the file is not there and if it does not fail the file should be there:

```
/**
 * Check if an asset exists. This will fail if the asset has a size < 1 byte.
 * @param context
 * @param path
 * @return TRUE if the asset exists and FALSE otherwise
 */
public static boolean assetExists(Context context, String path) {
    boolean bAssetOk = false;
    try {
        InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open(ASSET_BASE_PATH + path);
        stream.close();
        bAssetOk = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("IOUtilities", "assetExists failed: "+e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("IOUtilities", "assetExists failed: "+e.toString());
    }
    return bAssetOk;
}
```

Comment: This solution much more faster, then getting the whole asset's folder as list, and check the containment. (I measured ~50ms vs ~800ms on my device)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Resources.openRawResourceFd(int resId)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResourceFd%28int%29

Comment: This doesn't give any method to check for file's existence. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, it will throw a NotFoundException. You can catch it and do what you want.