# Checking existence of android assets folder html file

Tags: android, android-assets

I am passing the html file as "file:///android_asset/WebApplication/index.html". How can I check this file existence in android.

Comment: have you tried file.isExist?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8070231/

Answer (score 0):

[[Android Assets]: File or Folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477148/android-assets-file-or-folder)

[How to get all files from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368101/how-to-get-all-files-from-assets-folder)

```
File f=new File("file:///android_asset/");  
    File[] files=f.listFiles();
```

and if files return null den you understand folder is empty.

Comment: I am using "Arrays.asList(getResources().getAssets().list("")).contains(filename)" this code for checking the files in the assets folder. How can I check the files in the assets sub-directory. without hardcoding like specifying the folder name in the list("") method.

Comment: its so easy once u use getResources().getAssets() this after dat u know how much folder u have in assets folder den u can use loop of folder length den u can check how many file on ur folder if its not empty (use recursive function or call again and again if folder have sub folder)

Comment: Ya, I am getting the folder list, but facing difficult to convert this to file or directory. "List<String> list = Arrays.asList(getResources().getAssets().list(""))". I am using this for listing the directory. How can I convert this to file.?

Comment: u check just isDirectory function for counting how many directory u have .

Comment: File filefolder=new File(list.get(i).toString()); and checking the condition filefolder.isDirectory() which always fails.

Comment: u can use isdirectory function on ur path file or where u get ur path

Comment: "File filefolder=new File("file:/"+"//"+"//"+"android_asset/"+list.get(i).toString());". We need file as "file:///android_asset/myfolder/myfilename.extension" for validation. But the above statement always give the file path as "file:/android_asset/myfolder/myfilename.extension" that's why always the directory checking condition fails. How can I get absolute path of the assets folder alone.?